# How to make VB.NET refuse to automatically declare the FOR loop variable?

Tags: vb.net

I'm maintaining a project which has the following code:

```
For i = 1 to 9
    <do stuff>
Next
```

This works fine on the dev machine, but fails when it's pushed onto the production server, complaining that `i` is undeclared. This is, in fact, true; if I add the following assignment:

```
i = 5
For i = 1 to 9
    <do stuff>
Next
```

then both the production and the dev machines fail to run this, saying that `i` is undeclared.

What is making the dev machine allow an undeclared `i` in the `For` loop, and how do I disable this?

Comment: Assuming i is an integer change the for to For i as Integer = 1 to 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature called local type inference. With that you can declare variable without specifying type:

```
' Variable num is an Integer. 
Dim num = 5

' Variable dbl is a Double. 
Dim dbl = 4.113

' Variable str is a String. 
Dim str = "abc" 

' Variable pList is an array of Process objects. 
Dim pList = Process.GetProcesses()

' Variable i is an Integer. 
For i = 1 To 10
    Console.WriteLine(i)
Next
```

You can disable it using [`Option Infer Off` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) as a first line in a file, or for whole project:

- Click a project in *Solution Explorer*.
- Open the *Project Designer* by clicking *Property Pages* on the *View* menu.
- On the *Compile* tab, in the *Option Infer* box, click *Off*.

Comment: I updated your link to point to the English version of the page. (+1)

Comment: My _Property Pages_ doesn't have tabs, and doesn't seem to have _Option Infer_ anywhere. It has a list on the left, listing "References", "Build", "Accessibility", "Start Options", "MSBuild Options", "Silverlight Applications". I found the option in `web.config`, under `system.codedom`: `<providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>` - thanks for the hint!

Comment: You probably opened solution properties page, not a project one.

Comment: I don't think so; here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/gVVUast.png Solution properties look different, with two sections for "Common Properties" and "Configuration Properties". But the web.config option has definitely fixed the issue - once I knew what it was called.